# Laravel Vue.js will not bind to input text

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, binding, vue.js

I am using Laravel and want to create a simple edit application for editing a post. I am using Vue.js 2 to bind the data, but somehow it will not display it - and I am unsure what could be wrong. When I display the data using Vue's e.g  of `@{{ postData.title }}` it displays the title on the page. But I want to display the data inside a input so that it can be edited. The routing and everything is fine, because I get the correct URL and I can display the data in Vue just not in the textboxes. Thanks in advance.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div id="postEdit">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
        <meta id="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <h1>Edit your post</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
           @{{ postData.title }}
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" v-model="postData.title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="post">Post</label>
          <textarea name="post" rows="8" cols="80" id="post" class="form-control" v-model="postData.post"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Post" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Vue.js:

```
var edit = new Vue({
  el: '#postEdit',
  data: {
    postData: <?php echo $post ?>,
  },

  methods: {

  },
});
```

My controller:

```
   public function edit($id){
      $post = Post::find($id);
      return view('post.edit', compact('post'));
    }
```

Comment: Currently which value is shown in input box?

Comment: No value - it is empty. When I refresh the page the values appear for a split second and then disappears.

Comment: When you first load the page, can you share what's inside postData (view source)?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use PHP in JavaScript like that. Use a client side http client to request the post via an app call.

Y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶p̶h̶p̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶J̶a̶v̶a̶S̶c̶r̶i̶p̶t̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶.̶ ̶Y̶o̶u̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶m̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶p̶i̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶o̶s̶t̶ ̶f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶a̶s̶s̶i̶g̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶u̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶f̶u̶l̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶e̶i̶v̶e̶d̶.̶ ̶

Edit:

You don't have a `post` property on `postData`. You have the echoed object. Use `->attributesToArray()` and access the model attributes that way.

Comment: That does not make sense because it picks up the title in the @{{ postData.title }} just not in the input box and textarea. The data of the title displays correctly on the page, but not in input.

Comment: Are you reloading the page between every request?

Comment: You need to convert the post object to an array so it can be set as a proper js object. See my edit.